# Best way to embed Jupyter/IPython notebook information

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I just run across a problem when trying to ask help using Pandas DataFrames in Jupyper notebook.

More specifically my problem is what is the best way to embed iPython notebook input and output to StackOverflow question?

Simply copy&paste breaks DataFrame output formatting so bad it becomes impossible to read.

Which would be preferred way to handle notebooks with StackOverflow:

1. screenshot
2. link to gist with the notebook
3. converting notebook to HTML and embedding it
4. Something else what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link to a gist is by far the superior option from those you have listed as that means helpers can run your code pretty easily and debug it from there.

An alternative option is to post the code that creates your DataFrame (or at least a minimal example of it) so that we can recreate it. This is advantageous over a gist since helpers don't have to look and download the gist because the code is in the body of the question. Also, this method is superior since you may later delete the gist and so the question is now useless for future reference, but if your code is in the body of the question then all future users can enjoy it as long as SO lives :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to link a Jupyter notebook is via [Deepnote](https://deepnote.com/), which has all the benefits of a gist, but in addition:

- allows creating the notebook directly from a `.ipynb` file
- makes the notebook cloneable (and runnable) in the cloud

An example is [this Deepnote notebook](https://deepnote.com/publish/Unpivot-a-DataFrame-from-wide-to-long-format-lN7WlqOdSlqroI_7DGAkoA).

(Unfortunately, Stack Overflow does not allow embedding cells from the notebook at the time of writing, and only allows external links)